# Как я могу переместить картинку на моей HTML-странице?

Tags: html

У меня есть картинка, и мне нужно переместить ее под словом с тире, но я не могу это сделать

по какой-то причине он не хочет поднимать эту иконку и теперь я добавляю другие, а он ставит их еще ниже

код:

```
<a href="https://vk.com/feed"><img src="vk.png" 
height="70" width="70" style="margin-left: 1130px; margin-top: 0px;" ></a>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

весь код:

```
<html>
<head>



<title>текст</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <style>
        body{
              background: url(back.jpg) no-repeat;
              -moz-background-size: cover;
              -webkit-background-size: cover;
              -o-background-size: cover;
              background-size: cover;
            }

    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-attachment:fixed" topmargin="0">

<a href="file:///C:/Users/Леонид/Desktop/сайт/index.html"><img src="name.png" 
  height="175" width="290" style="margin-left: 80px; margin-top: 10px;" ></a>
<h1 style="position: absolute; top: 0; text-align: right; width: 87%;">Подпишись</h1>  
<img src="line.png" 
  height="180" width="260" style="margin-left: 750px; margin-top: 7px;" >
<a href="https://vk.com"><img src="vk.png" 
    height="70" width="70" style="margin-left: 1130px; margin-top: 0px;" ></a>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="line.png" 
  height="180" width="260" style="margin-left: 750px; margin-top: 7px;" >
```

У вас у картинки с линией высота указана 180 пикселей, из-за этого и получается дырка.

Answer (score 0):

А если применить `position:absolute; top:;` и `left:;` ?